# A determinant of a combination of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Following a book, I see a statement that reads

> we find that (18.7.11) is euqivalent to $$ l^k\left|u_{ij}^W-\frac{b_ib_j}{l} \right|=0 $$ which can be written as $$ l^{k-1}\left|u_{ij}^W\right|\cdot\left[l - \sum_{i,j=1}^k u_W^{ij}b_ib_j\right]=0 $$

To translate, the book says that given that $0\neq l\in\mathbb{R},\;{\bf b}\in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $0<{\bf U} \in M_k(\mathbb{R})$, then
$$ \det\left({\bf U} - \frac{{\bf b} {\bf b}^\top}{l} \right) = \det\left({\bf U}\right)\left[1 - \frac{{\bf b}^\top{\bf U}^{-1}{\bf b} }{l} \right]$$
Can anyone help me understand why that's true?

Comment: [rank 1 perturbation of matrix determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)

Comment: Thank you. Post as an answer.